# the result of third combo box should be decided by the results of other two combo box in VBA User form?

Tags: vba, combobox, userform

```
 Private Sub s11()
 If combobox1.Text = "CAV(Airlines, Airports, General and Light Aviation)" 
 And combobox2.Text = "Issue" Then
 UserForm1.combobox3.Value = "Completed"
 End If
 End Sub

 Private Sub Combobox3_Click()
 Call s11
 End Sub
```

Here Combobox1,combobox2 and combobox3 are the three comboboxes i
have selected and i want the result to show up on third combobox3
depending on the values of combo box 1 and combobox2

Comment: Do you want changing the value of a combo box and modify this change according to other combo boxes value? Is my understanding correct? If yes, why would you do such a thing? Would you like to let it change the value only in some conditions?

Comment: The Problem is Answer is not populating. It remains with the default value, but when i click the dropdown option, i am not able to select other options. even if i select other options from drop down list , it results in "Complete"

Comment: Please check my code now. i have made changes as per your advise.

Comment: `combobox1.Value` instead of `combobox1.Text` will be more appropriate. And where is the problem? Do you receive an error? If yes, what error and own which code line? If not, what is happening?

Comment: The value of combox 3 remains same with default value but when i try to select the dropdown value under combox 3 i end up getting the value = "Complete". i cant select any other dropdown option other than "complete". I dont want to click dropdown option for the answer to populate. i just want answer to populate as soon as i change the first two combox values

Comment: When you click on the combo box (triggering its Click event), are the other two combo boxes value the one you check? If yes, your code behaves as you built it... If you need to change the respective combo box value when one of the other two ones is changed, then use 'other combo box' `Change` event... But, in this way, why will it be a combo box and not a Text box?

Comment: you are correct . it is triggering the click event.

Comment: if i have one condition in IF statement then the result populates even before clicking but when i use AND operator in IF statement to include other condition then the result is not populating in the third combobox

Comment: Do i need to use Textbox Instead of combobox . why so? It wont work with combobox .is it?

Comment: It can work with combo box, but the combo is more complex and no point to use it for such a purpose. If you use a text box, use its 'Text' property (instead of 'Value')...